# dj-rest-auth token not deleted in backend after logout

Tags: python, reactjs, django, dj-rest-auth

I started using the django dj-rest-auth package with react and i ran across the following issue:

When i logout it will clear the key inside the local storage but not inside the Django backend.

When i go to the API endpoint page and click the "send post request" button it will do it, but it won't do it when i use my frontend to logout.

[image: dj-rest-auth]

This is the code i'm using to accomplish this:

navbar.js

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios"
import { AuthContext } from "../contexts/AuthContext";
import { API } from "../api"

export function Navbar() {
  const { user, logout } = useContext(AuthContext)
  const navigate = useNavigate()

    function handleSubmit() {
      axios.post(API.auth.logout)
        .then(res => {
          logout()
          navigate('/login')
        })
    }
```

api.js

```
const baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
const apiURL = `${baseURL}/api`

export const API = {
    auth: {
        login: `${baseURL}/dj-rest-auth/login/`,
        logout: `${baseURL}/dj-rest-auth/logout/`,
        passwordReset: `${baseURL}/dj-rest-auth/password/reset/`,
        passwordResetConfirm: `${baseURL}/dj-rest-auth/password/reset/confirm/`,
        signup: `${baseURL}/dj-rest-auth/registration/`,
        verifyEmail: `${baseURL}/dj-rest-auth/registration/verify-email/`
    }
}
```

app.js

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Navigate
} from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext, AuthContextProvider } from './contexts/AuthContext'

import { Login } from './components/Login'
import { Reset } from './components/Reset'
import { Navbar } from "./components/Navbar";
import { Signup } from "./components/Signup"
import { ConfirmEmail } from "./components/ConfirmEmail";
import { ResetConfirm } from './components/ResetConfirm'

function PrivateRoute({ children }) {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext)
  return user ? children : <Navigate replace to="/login" />
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <AuthContextProvider>
        <div>
          <Navbar />          

          {/* A <Routes> looks through its children <Route>s and
              renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
          <div className="max-w-4xl mx-auto py-5 px-4">
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/settings" element={<PrivateRoute><Settings /></PrivateRoute>} exact />
              <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} exact />
              <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} exact />
              <Route path="/reset" element={<Reset />} exact />
              <Route path="/password-reset/confirm/:uid/:token" element={<ResetConfirm />} exact />
              <Route path="/accounts/confirm-email/:key" element={<ConfirmEmail />} exact />
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </div>
      </AuthContextProvider>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: but how do you whethers its saving that token on backend or not ?

Comment: You mean how do i know that it didn't get deleted? I checked the Django backend.

Comment: But I don't think. Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37744963/drf-django-rest-auth-how-to-expire-or-delete-token

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently this is not possible so i started using JWT Tokens instead which are part of dj-rest-auth aswell:

```
REST_USE_JWT = True
```

More details on the JWT configuration can be found here: https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the authentication token in the headers in the API like

```
function handleSubmit() {
  axios.post(API.auth.logout, {}, {headers: "Token <auth_token>"})
    .then(res => {
       navigate('/login')
     })
}
```